# A tag for "Universal Windows Platform" that doesn't exceed the 25 character limit?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that [this question's title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129767/c-uwp-scan-for-music-files) started out with "UWP", which stands for "Universal Windows Platform". Chances are such questions will become more frequent, and thus it could be useful to have a specific tag for it (like WCF and WPF etc.).

Unfortunately, "universal-windows-platform" exceeds the 25 character limit for a tag name. Can "uwp" be used, or would that be too obscure?

What would be a solution?

Comment: I DuckDuckGoed "Universal Windows Platform" and got hits for "UWP", I don't think it'd be obscure as it's already being used.

Comment: Stack Overflow has [win-universal-app] (4209 questions) with synonym [windows-universal] (617 question), as well as [uwp] (2214 questions).

Comment: Huh, I thought we (by "we", I mean Stack Overflow the company, back when I worked there) upped the tag length limit to 35? Maybe it's site-specific.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young AFAIK is a per-site settings, the default is 25, but it can be longer. Manga & Anime has longer limit, since their topic tend to have very long names, but can't find the meta post.

Comment: Considering that the tag limit has now been increased, perhaps we should have `Universal-Windows-Platform` as a synonym for `uwp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[uwp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uwp) is the acronym used by microsoft commonly ([an example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide)).

[win-universal-app](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) or [windows-universal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) names were more commonly used for the platform that targeted Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, however I believe that having them as synonyms to UWP might be a good idea as googling those still returns documentations about UWP.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post this as an answer, however on Arqade Meta when discussing for tags, we usually post answers with our recommendations, let me know if I should move this to the comment section :)

Comment: Just like other SEs "_use comments to_ ask for clarification or _add more information_." I know that I meant to only add more information, and I think that was 200_success' intent too.
We should also "avoid answering questions in comments", so I'd say _don't move this to the comments_. :)